# Error en boot failed

Tags: windows, usb

quiero formatear mi computadora es una toshiba a travez de una usb booteable quiero  instalar el SO windows 10 que desacrgue desde la pagina oficial de microsoft pero cuando selecciono la prioridad de arranque para que sea la usb boteable la que arranque me aparece boot failed como puedo solucionarlo???

Comment: Has montado correctamente la imagen de Windows con [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/es_ES.html) / [Yumi](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) en el USB?. Adjunta fotos del error si puede ser

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes comprobar que tu unidad USB está como partición activa, eso se configura desde el administrador de discos de Windows.

Luego debes hacer el pendrive autoarrancable, para ello desde la línea de comandos de DOS vas hasta la carpeta BOOT de la carpeta de instalación y ejecuta el siguiente comando, tomando E como la letra donde tienes el USB, si lo tienes en otro sitio cámbialo:

```
BOOTSECT /NT60 E:
```

Todo esto lo tengo en un [vídeo de 4 minutos en YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SNMkQwwCAI) por si te facilita la configuración. También puedes utilizar aplicaciones de terceros para hacerlo, pero si sigues el vídeo es muy sencillo y seguro que lo consigues.

Saludos